# Basic android error (Beginner)

Tags: android

```
Sudoko Android requires .class compatibility set to 5.0. Please fix project properties.
```

What this error mean?
Please let me know if i need to paste some code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

> If you are using Eclipse SDK than
>   perform following steps to fix your
>   problem:
>
> Right click on your application name
>   (within Package Explorer view) ->
>   Android Tools -> Fix Project
>   Properties

**Source**:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/9580edf1ed579e4c/a29027e8ea268fa0?lnk=raot

Comment: That's strange... because: http://www.mailinglistarchive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg26081.html

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with the Android projet property, but with the Java Compiler Level. Go in Projet ->Properties -> JDK Compiler and make sure you are using Java 1.5 or Java 1.6.

Source:

[Problems importing existing project into eclipse](http://www.mail-archive.com/android-developers@googlegroups.com/msg39849.html)

Comment: Thank you, you are life saver. Tried everything and that one helped!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution ...this helps you...

```
Solution: 1. Fix project: Package Explorer -> Right click the project -> "Android Tools" -> "Fix Project Properties" 

2. Restart Eclipse: "File" -> "Restart"
```